# How to access database in ASP.Net Core2 cshtml file (View)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, dbcontext

I'm looking for a way to load (or gain access to a record of) a Database Table in View pages (cshtml) in ASP.Net Core 2.
I used to access the database by creating an object from DB Context. For example to populate a table in the MVC project (by using Razor engine) I could create an object and a table like this:

```
<table >
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    ProjectName.Models.ProjectNameEntities db = new ProjectName.Models.ProjectNameEntities();
    var CustomerTableObject= db.Customer.ToList();
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in CustomerTableObject)
        {
            <tr>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not ever access a database directly in a view. Instead, you can use a view component. Create the file `ViewComponents\CustomerTableViewComponent.cs`, with something like the following:

```
public class CustomerTableViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ProjectNameEntities _context;

    public CustomerTableViewComponent(ProjectNameEntities context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var customers = await _context.Customer.ToListAsync();
        return View(customers);
    }
}
```

Then, create the view, `Views\Shared\Components\CustomerTable\Default.csthml`. Inside:

```
@model List<Customer>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, where you want this table to appear add the line:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CustomerTable")
```